# restrict camera movement, Camera moves out of bounds

Tags: unity-game-engine, zooming, limit, pinchzoom, pinch

I'm creating a simple camera pan and scroll for my mobile game and need some help.
Right now with the code I have a player can scroll of the map I created.
I got the code from this youtube video (for context) https://gist.github.com/ditzel/836bb36d7f70e2aec2dd87ebe1ede432
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkYco_7-ULA&ab_channel=DitzelGames

Do you know how I could fix this?

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ScrollAndPinch : MonoBehaviour
{
#if UNITY_IOS || UNITY_ANDROID
    public Camera Camera;
    public bool Rotate;
    protected Plane Plane;

    public Transform Map;

    float distance;


    private void Awake()
    {
        if (Camera == null)
            Camera = Camera.main;
        Input.multiTouchEnabled = true;

    }

    private void Update()
    {

        //Update Plane
        if (Input.touchCount >= 1)
            Plane.SetNormalAndPosition(transform.up, transform.position);

        var Delta1 = Vector3.zero;
        var Delta2 = Vector3.zero;

        //Scroll
        if (Input.touchCount >= 1)
        {
            Delta1 = PlanePositionDelta(Input.GetTouch(0));
            if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                Camera.transform.Translate(Delta1, Space.World);
        }

    }

    protected Vector3 PlanePositionDelta(Touch touch)
    {
        //not moved
        if (touch.phase != TouchPhase.Moved)
            return Vector3.zero;

        //delta
        var rayBefore = Camera.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position - touch.deltaPosition);
        var rayNow = Camera.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);
        if (Plane.Raycast(rayBefore, out var enterBefore) && Plane.Raycast(rayNow, out var enterNow))
            return rayBefore.GetPoint(enterBefore) - rayNow.GetPoint(enterNow);

        //not on plane
        return Vector3.zero;
    }

    protected Vector3 PlanePosition(Vector2 screenPos)
    {
        //position
        var rayNow = Camera.ScreenPointToRay(screenPos);
        if (Plane.Raycast(rayNow, out var enterNow))
            return rayNow.GetPoint(enterNow);

        return Vector3.zero;
    }

#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put in the update a control with the bounds of your area with a bool like this :

```
if(Camera.transform.position.x > valuexmax || Camera.transform.position.x < valuexmin
      || Camera.transform.position.y > valueymax || Camera.transform.position.y < valueymin)
   {
     InBounds = false; //just a bool variable set to true in start
   }
```

And then you can put in the scroll something like this

```
if (Input.touchCount >= 1 && InBounds == true)
    {
        Delta1 = PlanePositionDelta(Input.GetTouch(0));
        if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
            Camera.transform.Translate(Delta1, Space.World);
    }

if(InBounds == false)
{   
      // reset position
 }
```

Comment: So I added what you said and I didn’t get an error (which was great). 
But I’m now stumped on how to make the camera stay inbounds. With your code once the camera gets out of bounds it just stops moving. I tried using a vector clamp but that was too messy and messed up the camera. 

Any ideas?

Comment: You can set an if(InBounds == true) and inside it use a transform variable called OldPos and set OldPos = Camera.transform.position and then if InBounds = false you can set camera position to OldPos and if it's not working then set oldpos - 0.1 on X and -0.1 on Y so it should move again the camera. Hope it's useful

Comment: Thank you Leoverload. This really helped me.